# Getting Twitter data with new API

Tags: php, json, twitter

As the twitter has updated its API recently, how can I get the **number of followers** of a person?

I could get such data with old API using following, but if I understand correctly, it will stop working at any time.

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter
```

How can I get the same data using their new API? I have checked their documentation but could not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well [straight from the new documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) it would seem the biggest difference is using `1.1` instead of `1`

You still retreive the data using JSON -

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json`

The docs say that the requirements are:

`Always specify either an user_id or screen_name when requesting a user timeline.`

And the returned object contains a "user" object, which contains the `followers_count` key:value pair.

```
{
    {
        ......
        user: {
            .....
            "followers_count" : int
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Type this: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2` and you will get error. I think it requires the authentication, but I do not know how to use that.

Comment: @user1251698 straight from the link on the right under 'RESOURCE INFORMATION', it says, 'Authencation : REQUIRED'. Clicking on that link takes you to the oAuth page...it has v1 and v1.1 requirements, clicking the sublink [Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth). It says you [create your application here](https://dev.twitter.com/apps) which is where you will be assigned your consumer key and secret key. From there, you can use [the documentation, again](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) in order to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is confusing. I did this recently for a client and it took me a while to figure out.

Read this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

To comply with v1.1 and get the data you want, you'll need to create a twitter application through your twitter account. The application will give you a couple of access keys. You'll use those access keys to obtain an access token, which you use to fetch your public data.

Here is the implementation I used: https://gist.github.com/luk3thomas/5243493